# Where does a 'build' folder belong in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, jenkins

I'm trying to get a handle on build tools, and I'm struggling with some basics.

I'm using XAMPP on a local Win7 machine. I've setup virtual hosts so I can work on multiple apps (.\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf)

So I have this:

```
app1
   php
      application
          cache
          config
          controllers
          core
          ...
          views
      assets
      system
   tests
   vendor

app2
   php 
      application
                         ...etc
```

Now I'm trying to install and setup Jenkins, using this guide: http://jenkins-php.org/automation.html

It then says under "Automation" .... *The build script assumes that the rule sets for PHP_CodeSniffer and PHPMD are located at build/phpcs.xml and build/phpmd.xml.*

Where does build come from? And where does it belong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the link that you're referring to is about Ant project and how to use it with Jenkins. I hope you're already done with Jenkins installation. In Ant, you have an XML file (usually *build.xml*) where you define various targets. Each target does some work such as cleaning up (compiled binaries of last build), compilation, packaging etc. You will have to go through the details if you aren't aware how Ant script works. As far as *build* folder is concerned, if you will go through the [link](http://jenkins-php.org/download/build.xml) provided for the build.xml file, you will see these lines:

```
<arg value="${basedir}/build/phpmd.xml"/>
<arg value="--standard=${basedir}/build/phpcs.xml"/>
```

In Ant, *basedir* is the place from where all the path calculations are done. For details about *basedir* and Ant scripting in general, please refer [this](http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html) link. Usually, your projects' output (*class* files, in case of Java projects) is placed under *build* folder. I have not worked on PHP projects but from the statement you've mentioned above i.e, "*The build script assumes that the rule sets for PHP_CodeSniffer and PHPMD are located at build/phpcs.xml and build/phpmd.xml.*", the Ant script assumes that both the XML files should be under the same *build* folder. You can change the location of those XMLs to any other location but *only* after you understand what you're doing.

After you're done with the customization in your build.xml file, you will then use this file in Jenkins (under `Build > Invoke Ant` section). Jenkins will simply run the script with your defined parameters, if any.

**Update:**
It's not really like the way you're thinking. I just explained the significance of *build* folder from my experience with *Java* projects. Here in *PHP*, if you go through the Ant file, you will realize that `build` directory is more like *the directory where all build-related scripts such as phpmd.xml, phpmd.xml etc. are kept*.

Ant is *not* creating the *build* directory. Instead, its *main* intention is to make sure that the *sub-directories within build directory are present* as is clear from the code mentioned below:

```
<target name="prepare" depends="clean" description="Prepare for build">
  <mkdir dir="${basedir}/build/api"/>
  <mkdir dir="${basedir}/build/coverage"/>
  <mkdir dir="${basedir}/build/logs"/>
  <mkdir dir="${basedir}/build/pdepend"/>
  <mkdir dir="${basedir}/build/phpdox"/>
</target>
```

The folders *within* build directory are in fact the directories where the *output of build.xml* gets stored as is clear from the below statement:

```
Executing the build.xml script will produce the following build directory:

build
|-- api ...
|-- coverage ...
`-- logs
    |-- checkstyle.xml
    |-- clover.xml
    |-- crap4j.xml
    |-- jdepend.xml
    |-- junit.xml
    |-- phploc.csv
    |-- pmd-cpd.xml
    `-- pmd.xml
```

Comment: Thanks, that is a great explanation. I get the feeling though, that I'm missing something. It sounds like a circular loop: Ant creates the "build" folder. Ant expects to find build instructions in the build folder (that it itself creates) ?!?!? What am I missing?